# LinearLayout in ScrollView not displaying button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

In the following code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="27sp"
                android:text="@string/create_card_text"/>

        <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textColor="#ff949494"
                android:text="@string/create_card_info_text_one"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:hint="Name"/>

        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/phone_number"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:hint="Phone Number"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"
                android:text="@string/create_card_next_button"
                android:onClick="next"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The button just does not shows up. What could be wrong?

Comment: Your marginleft is huuuuge!

Comment: @K_K try below code and let me know whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

You have set `android:layout_marginLeft="280dp"` so replace this with

`android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"` or something else

so basically your button's code will look something like this

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/next_button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:text="@string/create_card_next_button"
     android:onClick="next"/>
```

I think you have set margin left to `280dp` which is causing problem and making it out of your screen set it to `20dp` or as per your screen requirement as you have set other and it should work.